# C preprocessor adds trailing "1" after expanding a macro defined in a command line

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

```
$ echo 'MACRO();' | gcc -D'MACRO() hello' -E -P -
hello 1;
      ^ why 1?!!!!
```

Do you know why it adds trailing "1" after expanding the macro?

Comment: I know that I should have written `echo 'MACRO();' | gcc -D'MACRO()=hello' -E - | tail -n 1`. But what does this 1 mean? Is it a bug in _gcc_ compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [GCC preprocessor documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options):

> -D name
>
> Predefine name as a macro, with definition 1.
>
> -D name=definition
>
> Predefine name as a macro, with definition definition. The contents of definition are tokenized and processed as if they appeared during translation phase three in a #define directive.

So you want:

```
$ echo 'MACRO();' | gcc -D'MACRO()=hello' -E -P -
hello;
```

Note the equal sign in the definition.

As to why it does what it does without it:  Spaces are separators in the definition of preprocessor symbols.  So the preprocessor is assigning "hello" to the symbol. Then it's noticing that there's no equal sign in the definition, so it's also appending the default "1".  That's not a bug, it's just the case of a space "in" a preprocessor symbol.

```
$ echo 'MACRO();' | gcc -D'MACRO() hello=foo' -E -P -
hello foo;
```

Comment: Thank you! So `-D'MACRO() hello` (without equal sign) is an invalid parameter. But why doesn't it trigger invalid parameter error?

Comment: @anton_rh: the preprocessor vary rarely complains about anything, you have to be very careful with macros.  Personally I avoid anything that is not simple.